# combining different js objects and sorting them by a key

Tags: javascript

How can I combine following three or more objects and sorting them by the key "name" alphabetically?

```
var obj1 = {name: "BBBB", number: 2, task: "testing"};
var obj2 = {name: "AAAA"};
var obj3 = {name: "CCCC", number: 1};
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by combine? Will they have the one `name`property? Sharing the wanted output, and the code you tried will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj1 = {
  name: "BBBB",
  number: 2,
  task: "testing"
};
var obj2 = {
  name: "AAAA"
};
var obj3 = {
  name: "CCCC",
  number: 1
};

var obj4 = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
obj4.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(obj4);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can just use `[ ]` to combine them.